# Java OutOfMemoryError: Strange behavior

Tags: java, loops, data-structures

Below program (prog1) throws OutOfMemoryError error. Rightly so. But if I add sysout below line 5(prog2), it wont throw error. Any reason for this strange behaviour?

prog1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();     
    try {
        while (true) {
            myList.add("My String"); //5
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

prog2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();        
    try {
        while (true) {
            myList.add("My String");
            System.out.println(myList);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will eventually throw an `OutOfMemoryError`, it just takes longer because each iteration takes more and more time to print all of the elements of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version will also run out of memory eventually.  (If you don't get bored and kill it first.)

The problem is that the print statement is repeatedly printing a list that is getting longer and longer.

By the time you have added N items to the list in the second version, you will have printed lists of sizes `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N`.  That is `N * (N + 1) / 2` copies of the string `"My String"` ... and some more.  That is `O(N^2)`.

If you are writing that to a `/dev/null` it will take a long time.  If you write it to a file, longer.  If you write it to a console displaying on your screen ... come back in a few hours.

---

As an experiment, replace

```
    System.out.println(myList);
```

with

```
    System.out.print("X");
```

Now you will only print `O(N)` characters instead of `O(N^2)` ... and the OOME will happen a lot sooner.